# In Vim, is there a way to move an object/motion (word, character, visual selection, etc) horizontally in the line, shifting characters around it?

Tags: vim

For instance, I have the following line:

```
object     => "plaintext",
```

I want to move the word 'object' over to the right (so it's one space away from the '=>'), like this:

```
    object => "plaintext",
```

The only way I know of doing it would be (starting at the beginning of the line): `i    <esc>ea4x`, or the equivalent from another starting location. I'd love to do the same thing I do for moving lines, but horizontally:

```
" Move lines up/down
nnoremap <Down> :m+<CR>==
nnoremap <Up> :m-2<CR>==
vnoremap <Down> :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap <Up> :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option to just do the horizontal movement is the following:

- Provided you have already selected the text you want to move:

  ```
  :vnoremap <A-S-l> xp`[v`]
  :vnoremap <A-S-h> xhhp`[v`]
  ```
- In normal mode, to just move the word your cursor is over (in any character of that word). These mappings will let you in visual mode:

  ```
  :nnoremap <A-S-l> viwxp`[v`]
  :nnoremap <A-S-h> viwxhhp`[v`]
  ```
- In insert mode, to just move the word your cursor is over (in any character of that word). These two mappings will let you in visual mode:

  ```
  :inoremap <A-S-l> <Esc>viwxp`[v`]
  :inoremap <A-S-h> <Esc>viwxhhp`[v`]
  ```

With these mappings, you can:

- Move selected text to the right:
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>
- Move selected text to the left:
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

Basically, you just cut what you have selected, paste it appropriately and select again what you have just pasted.

Obviously you can select any mapping you like.

Comment: [This worked beautifully](https://github.com/zhimsel/dotfiles/commit/815fece20eab6a6e6f2bbe5ac1ae238bd94ff35e), thanks! I didn't know about `\`[` and `\`]`.

Comment: @zhimsel Thanks. I have just updated my answer including mappings for normal and insert modes.

Answer (score 5):

You could cut(delete) and paste(put) your whitespace. It's not glorious but it would work. However I feel like a better option would be to align your text by using [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) ([Aligning text with Tabular.vim](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/)) or [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align).

Using tabular you can do the following:

```
:Tabularize/=>/r1l1l1
```

There is also [exchange.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange), but that is just fancy delete and putting. [Swapping two regions of text with exchange.vim](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/swapping-two-regions-of-text-with-exchange-vim/)

Comment: You certainly can. The `r1l1l1` is for the alignment and padding. I would recommend reading `:h tabular-walkthrough` for more information. If tabular doesn't strike your fancy I recommend vim-easy-align as well. It is more interactive and may meet your needs better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip for [Tabularize](https://github.com/zhimsel/dotfiles/commit/2fb4993aa654d3ad408c4e39d149e051f5c4fc52). I'm trying to figure out if I can align text and pad to the left. Comment markdown is not letting me format this right, [see here for my example](https://gist.github.com/zhimsel/5ea953f5dec161c3b3f2)

Comment: (comments out of order, sorry) Hm, I did go through the walkthrough, but I'll take a closer look. Thanks!

Comment: The command, `:Tabularize/=>/r1l1l1`, in my post does the right alignment of your keys like you asked for.

Comment: [Indeed it does.](https://github.com/zhimsel/dotfiles/commit/010bc74a9fc2acddde52e767c88637aee5e94cb0) Thanks!